# How to permanently disable all eclipse validations?

Tags: eclipse, rtc

I'm using Rational Team Concert 5.0.2, it's based on eclipse helios. I have disabled and suspended all validators, but it doesn't seem to work.

[image]

The errors are mainly about unbound classpath variable or missing required library.

[image]

I don't build projects in RTC, only use it as a source control tool. So I really don't care about the errors. But a project policy was set to not allow check in source code if error occurs. So I have to manually delete all markers in **Problem** tab before that. However, the errors always come back after a restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In eclipse there are two "types" of errors. Errors are

- either relevant for eclipse to do its work (missing references, etc. hinder eclipse from compiling)
- or just useful information to the user, without inpact on normal eclipse features (invalid xmls, etc.)

The latter is called "validation" and can be disabled. You cannot disable "real" errors.

If you want to ignore "real" errors:

- Change the project type from java projects to plain "projects". For plain projects no classpath is needed.
- Or use the parent folder as eclipse project.
- Or close the error tab and just don't bother about red icons.
- If your check in policy is not practicable: **try to change that policy**

Comment: The project I involved is huge and has many components. I only care a portion of them and don't need those Java thing, it doesn't mean other developers don't need either. Plus I couldn't change the policy. It was set by some, you know, old school high level guys. Anyway, converting to normal projects solved my problem.

Comment: @Leo I absolutely understand - I know that type of *old school high level guys* :). Thanks for accepting!